Vertical alignment in tblr environment
I am trying to vertically center cell contents for a few columns. The manual says this is possible on page 5 using Q columns.
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{ipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {Q[1,c,m]Q[3,l,m]Q[1.5,c,m]Q[3.5,l,m]Q[8,l]},
  width = \linewidth,
  row{1} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white},
  hlines = {azure5,solid,0.4pt},
  vlines = {azure5,solid,0.4pt},
  vline{2-5} = {1}{white,solid,0.4pt},
  row{even} = {bg=azure9}
}
Id & Column A & Col B & Column C & Notes \\
1 & lorem & ipsum & dolar & \ipsum[1] \\
2 & lorem & ipsum & dolar & \ipsum[2] \\
3 & lorem & ipsum & dolar & \ipsum[3]
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

However, the above yields the following:

Anyone know what I am missing?

Vertically centre the tall last column which dictates the height of the row:
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{ipsum}


\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {Q[1,c]Q[3,l]Q[1.5,c]Q[3.5,l]Q[8,l,m]},
  width = \linewidth,
  row{1} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white},
  hlines = {azure5,solid,0.4pt},
  vlines = {azure5,solid,0.4pt},
  vline{2-5} = {1}{white,solid,0.4pt},
  row{even} = {bg=azure9}
}
Id & Column A & Col B & Column C & Notes \\
1 & lorem & ipsum & dolar & \ipsum[1] \\
2 & lorem & ipsum & dolar & \ipsum[2] \\
3 & lorem & ipsum & dolar & \ipsum[3]
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


